Difficult Fourier transform
I need to compute the Fourier transform of a simple rational function times hyperbolic secant distribution
InverseFourierTransform[2*w/Sinh[Pi*w]/(w - I), w, t, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]

MA runs forever... Reformulation in term of integral does not help either:
Integrate[2*w/Sinh[Pi*w]/(w - I)*Exp[-I*w*t]/(2 Pi), {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]

I suspect that with some tricks it can be computed in closed form.

I have doubts about its closed form. See ListPlot[  Table[{t,  Im[NIntegrate[      2*w/Sinh[Pi*w]/(w - I)*Exp[-I*w*t]/(2 Pi), {w, -Infinity,        Infinity}]]}, {t, -10, 10, 0.5}]] as a numeric result. ListPlot[ Table[{t,   Re[NIntegrate[ 2*w/Sinh[Pi*w]/(w - I)*Exp[-I*w*t]/(2 Pi), {w, -Infinity,  Infinity}]]}, {t, -10, 10, 0.5}]] looks as a white noise formed by round-off errors.

The result of ListPlot[ Table[{t,  Log[Im[NIntegrate[        2*w/Sinh[Pi*w]/(w - I)*Exp[-I*w*t]/(2 Pi), {w, -Infinity,          Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6,         Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"]]]/RealAbs[t]}, {t, -50,   50, 3}]] suggests  an Exp[-RealAbs[t]^c] decay.

Solution, using: Maple 2024.2:

$$\text{InverseFourierTransform}\left[\frac{2 w}{\sinh (\pi  w) (w-i)},w,t,\text{FourierParameters}\to \{1,1\}\right]=\\\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{2 w \exp (-i w t)}{(\sinh (\pi  w) (w-i)) (2 \pi )} \, dw=\\-\frac{2 i e^t \left(1+t+e^t t-\left(1+e^t\right) \log
   \left(1+e^t\right)\right)}{\left(1+e^t\right) \pi }$$
A nice plot:
 Show[{ListPlot[Table[{t, 
 Im[NIntegrate[
   2*w/Sinh[Pi*w]/(w - I)*Exp[-I*w*t]/(2 Pi), {w, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}]]}, {t, -10, 10, 0.5}]], 
 Plot[-((2 I E^
  t (1 + t + E^t t - (1 + E^t) Log[1 + E^t]))/((1 + E^t) \[Pi])) //
 Im, {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red]}]


EDITED:
For general a,b and c parameter looks like:
$$\text{InverseFourierTransform}\left[\frac{2 w \text{csch}(a\pi  w)}{b w-i c},w,t,\text{FourierParameters}\to \{1,1\}\right]=\color{blue}{\frac{2 i}{a b \left(1+e^{t/a}\right) \pi }-\frac{2 i c e^{-\frac{t}{a}} \, _2F_1\left(1,1+\frac{a c}{b};2+\frac{a
   c}{b};-e^{-\frac{t}{a}}\right)}{b (b+a c) \pi }}$$
for: $a>0$,$b>0$ and $c>0$
Workaround:
$Version
(*"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"*)   

LaplaceTransform[
InverseFourierTransform[
InverseLaplaceTransform[(2 w Csch[a*\[Pi] w])/(b*w - I*c), c, s], w,t, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {s > 0, a > 0, b > 0}], s, c, 
Assumptions -> {t > 0, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}] // Expand

(*(2 I)/(a b (1 + E^(t/a)) \[Pi]) - (2 I c E^(-(t/a))
Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + (a c)/b, 2 + (a c)/b, -E^(-(t/a))])/(
b (b + a c) \[Pi])*)

% /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1} // FullSimplify

(*(2 I E^t (-1 + (1 + E^t) Log[1 + E^-t]))/((1 + E^t) \[Pi])*)


Cannot reproduce it in Maple 2024. The command (inttrans:-invfourier(2*w/(sinh(Pi*w)*(w - I)), w, t) assuming t::real) returns -4*invfourier(w/((exp(Pi*w) - exp(-Pi*w))*(-w + I)), w, t) and  the command (int((2*w*exp(-I*w*t))/(2*sinh(Pi*w)*(w - I)*Pi), w = -infinity .. infinity) assuming t::real) returns the input. Online help of Maple says the command was updated in Maple 2019.

Thank you very much, it is really useful for me! I will wait with acceptance a bit as I am curious if a MA solution would be possible.

However, (inttrans:-invfourier(2*w*csch(Pi*w)/(w - I), w, t) assuming t::real) outputs 2*I*exp(-t)*(exp(-t)*ln(exp(-t) + 1) + t*exp(-t) + ln(exp(-t) + 1) + t - 1)/((exp(-t) + 1)*Pi), but the plot of its imaginary part differs from the plot in your answer.

Help to Maple 2024 says there are some improvements in inttrans , presenting  examples. Also InverseFourierTransform in Mathematica  is fourier in Maple and (inttrans:-fourier(2*w*csch(Pi*w)/(w - I), w, t) assuming t::real)  does produce 4*I*exp(t)*(ln(exp(t) + 1)*exp(t) - t*exp(t) + ln(exp(t) + 1) - t - 1)/(exp(t) + 1).

I think this is implemented as a table value because Maple fails with (int((2*w*exp(-I*w*t))/(2*sinh(Pi*w)*(w - I)*Pi), w = -infinity .. infinity) assuming t::real) and (int(2*w*exp(-I*w*t)*csch(Pi*w)/((w - I)*2*Pi), w = -infinity .. infinity) assuming t::real).

The command of Maple 2024 inttrans:-invfourier(4*I*exp(t)*(ln(exp(t) + 1)*exp(t) - t*exp(t) + ln(exp(t) + 1) - t - 1)/(exp(t) + 1), t, w) fails.  Сan't go back.

@yarchik .I update my answer :)

@MariuszIwaniuk Perfect!
